# Android Volley Request Gson

Tags: java, android, android-volley, gson

Looking to use the class on the android developers website that uses Volley and Gson to fetch and deserialize json data from a url to parse into an array. I'm still a beginner so I was trying to instantiate the class but I'm not sure how to format the parameters. Tried looking for implementation but they seem to use other API's in addition. The returned json only has one field and value so class object clazz has one field.

```
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {
private final Gson gson = new Gson();
private final Class<T> clazz;
private final Map<String, String> headers;
private final Listener<T> listener;

/**
 * Make a GET request and return a parsed object from JSON.
 *
 * @param url URL of the request to make
 * @param clazz Relevant class object, for Gson's reflection
 * @param headers Map of request headers
 */
public GsonRequest(String url, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> headers,
        Listener<T> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.headers = headers;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
    listener.onResponse(response);
}

@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String json = new String(
                response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(
                gson.fromJson(json, clazz),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}
}
```

Just looking to get the example up and running So it at least can receive the data to display on screen.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define a model class based on your expected JSON response.

For example, If your JSON is Array of Users, then model class will look like this,

Users.Java

```
public class Users extends Object implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @SerializedName("users")
    private ArrayList<User> arrListUser;

    public ArrayList<User> getArrListBusinessObj() {
        return arrListUser;
    }

    public static class User extends Object implements Serializable  
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private String user_id;
        private String name;
        private String artwork;

        public String getBusinessObjId() {
            return user_id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getArtwork() {
            return artwork;
        }

    }
}
```

Then where you are receiving your network response, call below method :

```
Users users = (Users)gson.fromJson(data, Users.class); //data is string form response from server
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I see that implementing the model class and Gson would map java variables to there corresponding json titles. Essentially what im trying to do is fetch and parse json into an array. The user has to make a selection from this array to decide what to fetch next. User has to pick an option before next fetch, would I have to create a separate class for each request to match the json fields or can I put it all into one class

Comment: Also what would instantiating your request look like with the gson class.

GsonRequest<User> request = new GsonRequest("url", USERS, ?, ?);

Comment: 1. If the response from the selected option by user is same as Users format, then you can use the same class. There is no need to create separate class for that, even if slight difference in the fields of Users, then also same class would work, as the fields which are not in response set as their default values (such as 0 for int and null for String etc..)   2. Request format would be same as you mentioned including your listeners, in my case I am making request from Manager class or View class and implement the listeners in the same, and then passing them into the request.